# Why is using a variable array length forbidden in C++, despite not changing it after declaration?

Tags: c++, iso

Let's say that we have 2 code samples, A and B:
A.

```
int n;
cin>>n;
//n is read as 2483
//n never changes beyond this point
int a[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
cin>>a[i];
```

B.

```
int n;
cin>>n;
//n is read as 2483
//n never changes beyond this point
int a[10000];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
cin>>a[i];
```

Why is A "forbidden" by ISO, despite attempting to save memory based on the current needs, with B being preferred, even though it's wasting some memory (e.g. allocating memory for 10000 ints instead of the required, let's say, 2483 ints)?
**Can someone please explain this to me, including the technical details?**

Comment: (a) because the C++ Standard says (automatic and static storage duration) arrays of unknown size __at compile time__  are not allowed. (b) use `std::vector<int>`

Comment: You're not saving memory because the stack has a fixed size.

Comment: why do you think changing n after the array declaration would make it any different? How else do you define 'not changed' at compile time than const?

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm asking why doesn't the C++ standard allow it. More exactly, what technical details determined ISO to say that you should know the array size at compile time?

Comment: @Sopel Because I thought that the main concern is not to increase n after the array is declared, as it could make loops go outside the allocated memory, therefore creating undefined behaviour.

Comment: @John why the Standard doesn't allow it is usually off topic - answers might need to go back almost 40 years or there might even be no answer other than _"because"_  So questions of that type usually fall into the __Too Broad__ category of off-topic question.

Comment: My guess would be that with variable length arrays it's easier to get into a problematic situation (due to limited stack space), and a more robust solution already exists - dynamically allocated memory (especially with std::vector). So there isn't really a compelling use case to support variable length arrays.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish I did some reaearch in the meantime. Apparently, not having a constant array length doesn't allow you to declare it on the heap by using the `static` keyword. But if you don't use it, I don't think it provides any advantage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)